# How to calculate the original x and y from the transform attribute?

Tags: c#, svg, inkscape

I have a problem with transform attribute of flowroot tag in svg document :

```
<g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <g
       transform="translate(-871.96706,1441.3237)">
      <flowRoot
         xml:space="preserve"
         id="flowRoot4433"
         transform="translate(317.05134,-1593.0553)">
        <flowRegion
             id="flowRegion4435">
          <rect
             id="rect4437"
             width="281.93622"
             height="428.39651"
             x="784.78339"
             y="473.07156" />
        </flowRegion>
          <flowPara
             id="flowPara4439">Your response is requested by
          </flowPara>
      </flowRoot>      
    </g>
  </g>
```

Above svgdoc contains 1 flowroot. The parent of the flowroot tag is g. Now my problem is the transform attribute which is present in both nodes (flowroot and its parent g). I want to calculate the original x and y of the flowroot . How can i do this in this situation ?. And it will be much better if there is any option present in inkscape editor so that when we create a new svg, the transform attribute will not generate with the nodes ?

Comment: Do you want to do this programmatically, with C#? You can use Inkscape on the command line, with `query` arguments, to get bounding box information. If you want to get the details of the flowRoot without the transformation applied, take a copy of the document, remove the transformation using an XML library, and then call Inkscape on the CLI as above. Not as elegant as using a native library maybe, but certainly it will work.